# Ftp command syntax to connect to Windows Azure

Tags: linux, azure, ftp

I'm trying to FTP to my Windows Azure Web App because I want to view the files that are there.  My console says:

> **ftp host name:**
> ftp://some-subdomain-012.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net
>
> **deployment / ftp user:**
> user\user

So from the command line I'm running

```
ftp 'user\user@'ftp://some-subdomain-012.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net
```

This opens up a prompt right away that says

> Name or service unknown

I do know the password, but I'm not prompted for it.  How can I FTP to my Web App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in the URL the username goes after the protocol prefix (the `ftp://`):

```
ftp://user\user@some-subdomain-012.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net
```

---

But anyway, you do not specify a URL on a `ftp` command-line. The common *nix `ftp` accepts hostname only on its command-line:

```
ftp some-subdomain-012.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net
```

Then you will be prompted for an username and a password.